# 3d spatial objects in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, spatial

Is there any way I can define a 3D solid within SQL Server using the spatial data type?

If so, can I see an example of how this would be done? say, just a 1x1x1 simple cube?
Would I have to define 6 polygons (1 for each face of the cube) and use those together somehow?

Everything I have read online tends to show examples purely with 2D shapes. I do know the Point type can handle X,Y,Z (and M) - So spatial 3D is possible, but I am finding it hard to get good examples. Especially of polygons / solids.

I guess if this is possible, it leads onto my next question: I would love to use some of the spatial methods that are available: STIntersection(), STContains() etc. Against these 3D objects. And because we are in 3D, a STVolume() function would be fantastic! But that is something I would have to roll myself I guess.

Perhaps there is a library full of SQL CLR Types and Spatial Extension methods that I am in need of?

Thank you.

Comment: Think this may be of interest (though I haven't tried it myself): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2008/11/01/sql-2008-spatial-samples-part-2-of-n-background-on-spatial-types-well-known-text-wkt.aspx

Comment: `DECLARE @3D as GEOMETRY = 'MULTIPOINT( (12 8 10), (15 5 5), (10 5 7))'` yip cool - i understand that for points around a 3D triangle, but polygons? so may `'MULTIPOLYGON'` is a good start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D spatial objects have been requested (on Connect: [Provide support for 3D Geo-Spatial Data](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/349552/provide-support-for-3d-geo-spatial-data)) as far back as 2008.

As you mentioned, it is possible to utilise X,Y,Z and M to represent points with elevation, but *there is no direct support for manipulating 3D objects* yet.

> The following example creates a Point instance with Z (elevation) and
>   M (measure) values and uses Z to fetch the Z value of the instance.
>
> ```
> DECLARE @g geometry;
> SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(1 2 3 4)', 0);
> SELECT @g.Z;
> ```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933920%28SQL.100%29.aspx).

There was no mention of this or other 3D features in [New Spatial Features in SQL Server 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226407)

Comment: Ha! that would explain why I don't see any examples that make any real use of the Z coordinate.

Comment: What is measure?

Comment: @liang From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/m-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15):
The M (measure) value of the geometry instance. The semantics of the measure value are user-defined.