# How can I create and query 3D Spatial Objects in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, 3d, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

Instead of using the 2D Spatial Data Type (multipolygon) to create a 3D geometry object, is there any other way of creating and querying 3D Solids? Any library with Spatial Extension methods that allows us to support 3D in SQL Server?

I am looking for something similar to polyhedral surfaces and TIN in postGIS and methods like ST_3DIntersects()

Comment: The following example creates a Point instance with Z (elevation) and M (measure) values and uses Z to fetch the Z value of the instance.

DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(1 2 3 4)', 0);
SELECT @g.Z;

Comment: @Mani, yes, that will include elevation, but the Spatial functions do not include elevation in their calculations.  For instance, this will return 0. SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('Point(0 0 0)', 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('Point(0 0 100)', 4326))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3d spatial objects in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887748/3d-spatial-objects-in-sql-server)